# Is it wise to disable browser link option in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5, browser-link

I am making an application in asp.net MVC 5 in which i am using highcharts to show the meter readings
I was facing an issue that whenever i want to see large amount of data(points) in charts it hangs the page for a long time and then it make it unresponsive or make it run 
I searched many articles and found that boost.js module is efficient way for view large data points 
So i just added the script but still my page hangs 
I inspected the elements and in console i found browser link errors
So i disabled the option for browser link and bingo it works fine now

I just want to ask that is it a good approach to disable it ? Or is there any other way that i can do my task(s) while still enabling browser link ?

I also want to know what does browser link do?

Comment: You can use Browser Link to refresh your web application in several browsers at once

Comment: ok but is it wise to disable it or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Browser Link" you can see what are the browser are attached with Visual Studio. it help web developer while working on multiple browser simultaneously and wanted to test the application based on some code or style change.if you don't want to test application on multiple browser at particular time of instance. you can disable it.

Source : http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/08/30/refreshing-browsers-directly-from-visual-studio-2013/